# Yii2 Model search query

Tags: yii2

How can I add where condition to my Articles model so that slug(From category model) is equal to $slug?

And this is a function that Gii generated:

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Categories::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

Here's my code:

```
    public function specificItems($slug)
    {
    $query = Articles::find()->with('category');
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),'pageSize' => 12]);
    $articles = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();
    return ['articles' => $articles,'pages' => $pages];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query should contain columns from both article and category table. For that you need to use `joinWith()`.

```
$result = Articles::find()
    ->joinWith('category')
    ->andWhere(['category.slug' => $slug])
    ->all();
```

Where 'category' is then name of your category table.

However, in your code you deviate from certain best practices. I would recommend the following:

- Have both table name and model class in singular (`Article` and `article`). A relation can be in plural, like `getCategories` if an article has multiple categories.
- Avoid functions that return result sets. Better return ActiveQuery class. If you have a query object, all you need to get the actual models is `->all()`. However, you can further manipulate this object, add more conditions, change result format (`->asArray()`) and other useful stuff. Returning array of results does not allow that.
- Consider extending `ActiveQuery` class into `ArticleQuery` and implementing conditions there. You'll then be able to do things like `Article::find()->joinWith('category')->byCategorySlug('foo')->all()`.